# fullcalendar selectMinDistance not respecting distance when unselecting

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am using fullcalndar [selectMinDistance](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectMinDistance)

example init:

I think this works by pixels ratio.  I've set this to `selectMinDistance: 155`

```
            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
                selectable: true,
                eventOverlap: true,
                selectOverlap: true,
                validRange: {
                    start: year + '-05-20',
                    end: year + '-11-15'
                },
                selectMinDistance: 155,
...
```

It works great because i want a minimum of 3 days selected.  However, when the user selects, then decides on that same mouse down to unselect, he can then unselect and bring it down to one day.  Kind of defeats the purpose.

Does anyone know if there is something in FullCal to prevent this from happening or a good fix?  I have not found anything in the docs that can help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my application `selectMinDistance` was not the best approach, and I was pointed out to use `selectAllow` found [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectAllow) instead that works great.

I'm not sure why I didn't find it searching online the first time.

To prevent users from selecting dates lower than a set count of days, you use this function and throw a true or false for it to be selectable to the user

my example usage

```
            var year = new Date().getFullYear();

            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
                selectable: true,
                eventOverlap: true,
                selectOverlap: true,
                validRange: {
                    start: year + '-05-20',
                    end: year + '-11-15'
                },
                //  selectMinDistance: 155,  this will not work for deselecting
                selectAllow: function(selectInfo){
                    console.log(selectInfo);

                    //  create a day
                    var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
                    var startDay = selectInfo.start;
                    //  FullCalendar always gives next next day of select end day, so do minus one day
                    var endDay = selectInfo.end - oneDay;
                    var count = Math.round(Math.abs((startDay - endDay) / oneDay));
                    //  starts at 0, so add to start at 1
                    var dayCount = (count + 1);
                    if(dayCount >= 3){
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        return false;
                    }


                },
...
```